# Is there a "fix" for Adobe Premiere Pro so it doesn't degrade sharp black lines and soften vivid colors?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, hardware

I captured video output from a computer program using Xbox Game Bar in Windows 10.  It looks good.  After cropping in Adobe Premiere Pro, my black lines are fuzzed, the vivid colors are degraded, and there appears to be image "echoes" from compression.  The final output is here, and I would like to do better:

Any ideas?

(The video output from Adobe was bad before the upload to YouTube; the thumb on the video start is good.)

Comment: Which video codec has been used to record the video? Which export settings did you use (esp. format, preset and target bitrate)?

Comment: @Matt -Thanks for your help. I've been through the tutorials and every menu and button I can find.  I checked that I do have the current drivers for my Intel HD Graphics 4600 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970.  In the Xbox game settings, I have image quality set to high, and the only other control is fps.  So, I really don't know where to look for my codec or target bitrate.

Comment: Nevermind the recording codec, then. The other parameters I meant can be found in Premiere. Can you tell us what you set in Premiere when you went to File-> Export -> Media... in order to export the video?

Comment: @Matt - In Adobe Premiere Rush 2021, File -> New, Project, Share, Exit.  That's it.  Share-> Local, YouTube, Facebook, Instagram, Behance. Facebook-> Advanced Settings = Automatic, 1080p, 30 fps, stereo, quality= high.  Instead of automatic, I could bump this up to Facebook 2160p 4K Ultra HD.

Comment: For 30,000 graphics frames at 1000 x 1000 coming out of Mathematica and playing for 45 minutes, IDK if an i7 at 4 GHz, 32 GB RAM, and 150 MB internet will handle that,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as we've found out in the comments, you actually use Premiere Rush and not Premiere Pro. There is a difference, Premiere Pro is much more complex but it also enables you to take control of many more aspects of the video making process.

The problem is most likely due to compression with a target bitrate that's too low. Rush is optimized for quick social media video sharing and this means they expect videos to be about a person talking about something filmed in front of a mostly static background, for example. They didn't have videos as yours in mind that require higher bitrates to look sharp and clean.

Normally I don't use Rush, but tried it to check what can be done in your case. Unfortunately, I don't see any option you can try. Setting the quality to high is already the best you can do. Using the 4k preset may help if the original clip has been recorded at 4k.

Another option you can try is to install [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use it from the command line. A question that deals with adding the crop effect, you need, is this one: [How can I crop a video with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a GUI tool, that uses ffmpeg and another alternative to try.

Or you could try Premiere Pro (if it's not in your subcription plan you could still try it for a number of days for free). However, both Premiere and ffmpeg are more complex.

It might be good to record another 5 min clip to save time when you try to find out the highest bitrate you need to make it look pleasant, yet still produce videos that are suitably small for upload to the web.

Comment: You are correct - I do not have Pro.  I am sorry about that mistake.  I will upgrade, and other consumers need to be aware of this difference.